# 301 redirects .htaccess file http-https

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, ssl

I have set up the following within my .htacess file: 
A redirect from non www to www 
And http to https

This seems to work fine if I access non www file it will forward to

The problem is, if I access an individual page using non https it'll still render and not forward to https version.

How am I able to correct this? 
    RewriteOptions inherit
    
    RewriteEngine on

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mywebsite.co.uk [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.myswebsiye.co.uk/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mywebsite\.co\.uk$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.mywebsite\.co\.uk$
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ "https\:\/\/www\.mywebsite\.co\.uk\/" [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to replace both force `WWW` and force `HTTPs`:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
```

The above code integrates the both, forcing `WWW` and forcing `HTTPs`.

Comment: So if I typed a URL of my page and used non https with above code it should redirect?

Comment: I have added the .htaccess file I currently have

Comment: Anything under the `#End Wordpress`, Replace with what I've put above. The above should turn a URL like this: `http://example.com` into `https://www.example.com`

Comment: Even if I type http/random page of my site that'll forward to the https version of that page

Comment: Why are you so reluctant to test it...?

Comment: I have but if i type `http://www.mysite.co.uk` it forwards to `https://.www.mysite.co.uk/` it says DNS address could not be found. If i type `mysite.co.uk` it forwards to `https://www.mysite.co.uk` but problem is still that if someone were to type `http://www.mysite.co.uk/sample/` it doesn't redirect to the https version

Answer (score 0):

I have some problem like you, you can edit Your .htaccess to :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{ENV:HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]

# BEGIN WordPress
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```